# Funding opportunities for non-european people going to Europe for a PhD in TCS

Tags: soft-question

There are two chinese students who would like to come to Spain to pursue a PhD in TCS in our group. I know of course the funding possibilities in my country but wonder if you know any European and non-European and Chinese funding calls or opportunities for doing PhD.

An extension of this questions; is it there around any funding/grant stack exchange site or which ones do you use to track grants?

Comment: We get a booklet 3 times a year full of all sorts of funding schemes. I'd check with the research office; there are often bilateral exchange agreements.

Comment: to whoever downvoted, it would be helpful if you explained why.

Comment: I did. It's important for a soft question to be more specific and provide resources for context.

Comment: yes, without grant resources, the research context dissapears. please tell me which concrete you need to be more specific and I will explain it more in detail

Comment: There is FP7, Marie Curie, etc.

Comment: FP7 I know, but do not know about the other "etc", any hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never having worked or studied in Spain, I can not really help with local information. However, as I mentioned in the comments, the most obvious source for such funding in European universities (aside from internal university or departmental sources and local research councils) would be funding from the [European Research Council](http://erc.europa.eu/). The ERC has many different kinds of grants, including training networks and personal grants, which can often be used to fund overseas students from. Additionally, the European Commission offers funding for postgraduates and postdocs via [Marie Curie actions](http://ec.europa.eu/research/mariecurieactions/).

Further, there is the [China Scholarship Council](http://en.csc.edu.cn/) which also offers support for students wishing to study abroad.

Then there are the industry scholarships: [Google](http://research.google.com/university/relations/doctoral_fellowships_europe.html), [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/university/phdfellowship/), [Microsoft](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/collaboration/global/apply-europe.aspx#criteria), etc.

If either of the students is female, then there are more options (see Google's [Anita Borg scholarship](http://www.google.com/anitaborg/), etc.).

Lastly, many European countries have bilateral agreements with China or Chinese institutions which may be another potential source of funding.

Answer (score 4):

Recently, a new Sino-Danish institute was announced, [Center for the Theory of Interactive Computation(CTIC)](http://ctic.au.dk/). From what I've read, I got the impression that Chinese students are welcome to visit Denmark for their PhD and vice versa.

You will probably be aware of the [Erasmus Programme](http://ec.europa.eu/education/lifelong-learning-programme/doc80_en.htm), however I am not sure if Chinese students can apply to it directly, they can certainly do once they join a European university as students and spend a seimester visiting another university.